# How to represent allocating resources to multiple projects in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, database-design

I have a SQL Server database with an Access front end where I need users to be able to allocate resources to multiple projects at once. For example, we have a stock of a particular part that is used in a number of mechanical assemblies and we need to allocate these parts to the particular assemblies for production.

How do people normally represent data with these requirements?

Currently my data is stored as follows:

```
Resource | A     | B     | C    (etc.)
---------+-------+-------+------
a        |  10   |  20   | NULL
b        |  11   | NULL  | 31
c        |  12   | NULL  | NULL
d        | NULL  |  40   | NULL
```

Where A, B, C are different projects.

*Advantages*:

- Easy visualisation and updating of Resources across all projects

*Disadvantages*:

- Database structure changes every time a project is added or finished..
- .. therefore many queries need to be rewritten/dynamic
- Difficult to get aggregate resource allocation summaries
- If old projects are retained, the table could easily exceed the column count limit

**Alternatives**

It seems to me that a more 'standard' representation would be a table as below. However, I have found it more or less impossible to present this to the user in a way that will allow easy visualisation and resource allocation over multiple projects.

```
ID   | Project | Resource | Quantity
-----+---------+----------+----------
1    |    A    |    a     |    10
2    |    A    |    b     |    11
3    |    A    |    c     |    12
4    |    B    |    a     |    20
5    |    B    |    d     |    40
6    |    C    |    b     |    31
```

*Advantages*:

- No structural changes when adding/removing projects
- Easy resource summaries
- Easy archiving of old projects

*Disadvantages*:

- Views that recreate the interface of the top example using JOINs will only allow editing of one column at a time and will not allow insertion or deletion by updating from/to NULL:

e.g.

```
-- 'Resources' table has resource ID as primary key (& other info about resource), 
-- 'ProjectResources' is the 'standard' table above
SELECT ResourceTable.ID, ProjA.Quantity AS A, ProjB.Quantity AS B, ProjC.Quantity AS C
FROM Resources 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProjectResources.Quantity, ProjectResources.Resource
               FROM ProjectResources
               WHERE ProjectResources.Project = 'A') AS ProjA 
    ON Resources.ID = ProjA.Resource
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProjectResources.Quantity, ProjectResources.Resource
               FROM ProjectResources
               WHERE ProjectResources.Project = 'B') AS ProjB 
    ON Resources.ID = ProjB.Resource
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProjectResources.Quantity, ProjectResources.Resource
               FROM ProjectResources
               WHERE ProjectResources.Project = 'C') AS ProjC
    ON Resources.ID = ProjC.Resource
```

- Using an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger on the above view can make it fully editable, but using this view in any further queries to add information (e.g. the 'stock' of the resource that we're allocating) make these fields read only (error along lines of 'field cannot be updated because it  it participates in a JOIN and has an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger')

Both of the above options require that the front end can cope with a varying number of table columns, which is a bit awkward, though in the second case this requirement can be limited only to specific circumstances.

Are there any other options on how to represent this data and allow easy editing that I have missed?

Comment: In it's current form, this question is a bad fit for Stack Overflow (it's too broad in my opinion), but might fit better with https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Your current database schema is not desirable for the reasons you listed. You are probably better off making the schema sensible and then dealing with the view in your UI rather than producing a bad schema to suit a particular view (if you want other views too, you'll be back in the same bucket with a hard-to-use schema for the new view).

While it's possible to produce the view as a crosstab query in Access, you will not be able to edit it (same as you found for your query; you are essentially building a crosstab query manually there).

A potential solution is to generate a temporary table in the front-end with the desired projects as columns (perhaps a subset of all projects), populate it with the resource data from the real table and display it as a datasheet. It will be editable and you can write changes back to the real table. It requires coding but it resolves the disadvantages.

Comment: Also be aware of the limitations when multiple edits can occur at the same time. Essentially the last person to save will overwrite any other changes - unless you implement some sort of "edit in progress" flag to prevent anyone else starting to edit, but that has a heap  of problems in itself.